# webApi is using headers request,how to get the response

Tags: cors, http-headers, cross-domain, fetch-api

url is 'http://*.*.*/api/v2/******/slide-ads?role=C&showType=app&type=activity'

method is 'get'

headers set

```
            key 'appVer'


          value   '4.0.0'
```

if I using postman

You can get the JSON object,

but using fetch or jquery , i can't get the response!

```
var vheaders = {
  "appVer": "4.0.0"          
};
fetch(URL, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: vheaders
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(e => console.log("Oops, error", e))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response the server’s returning is an error message:

```
$ curl -i -H "Origin: http://example.com" \
'http://123.56.230.49/api/v2/freekeers/slide-ads?role=C&showType=app&type=activity'
HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Mon, 31 Jul 2017 20:30:23 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

{"code":"0000","message":"请求无法获取当前版本号"}
```

Notice the `HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity`.

And the Chinese text there translates at *“Couldn’t get the current version number.”*

And that error response also doesn’t include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, so your browser won’t allow your frontend JavaScript code to access the response body.

For cross-origin requests, the CORS protocol requires browsers to disallow access to response bodies from frontend code unless `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is included in the response.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS has more details.

Comment: open this web API test [link] (http://getman.cn/)                  Request->Header->insert             appVer:4.0.0 then you can see the response

Comment: *Request->Header->insert appVer:4.0.0*? So that’s showing the *request* headers, right? It’s not showing the response, right?

Comment: open www.getman.cn then choose Header ,then add the text appVer:4.0.0 into textarea, click blue button , then can see the response!

Comment: yeah sorry not going to spend time messing around at that site. I don’t know what that www.getman.cn site is nor what it’s doing nor how it relates to the existing question you posted here. But the answer here already provides an explanation of the problem described in the question—the answer explains what’s happening in the browser and why. It’s unclear to me at this point what else you want to know

Comment: getman.cn is like a postman api dev tool , you say you can't get the response ,so i just want you use this tools to see the response , this problem confuse me a long time , but still havn't  work out! if i use the apitool can get the response , but js doesn't worked!

Comment: If getman.cn is like Postman my guess it that it’s making the request on the server side, from the backend, and so getting the response back on the backend side. In that case, there are no restrictions on anything being able to access the response from a cross-origin request. You will only it cross-origin restrictions when the request is made from *frontend* code running in a browser—because the browser is the only client that enforces cross-origin restrictions. I hope that explanation helps to clear up the differences in behavior you’re noticing

Comment: thanks a lot , I 've handle this problem ! just because server have  cross-origin limit , I set the config of nginx.conf (Reverse Proxy) ,it worked !  so glad with you'r answer , It's helpfull for me !